# How can I escape special characters names?

Tags: typescript, jsdoc

I'm documenting data that's parsed from a CSV, so the property names may contain spaces, `#`, etc.

How can I document them?

```js
/**
 * @typedef {Object} EmployeeCsv
 * @property {string} Emp#
 * @property {string} First Name
 */
```

```js
console.log(emp["Emp#"]);
```

```
[tsserver] Property 'Emp#' does not exist on type 'EmployeeCsv'. Did you mean 'Emp'? [E]
```

I've tried `\`, `'`, and `"`, but they seem to have no effect or result in an "expected identifier" error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce this in the Playground with Typescript 4.3.5. I couldn't make the syntax work using the `@typedef {Object} EmployeeCsv` syntax you described. As in [jsdoc/jsdoc#1468](https://github.com/jsdoc/jsdoc/issues/1468), it seems that VSCode and Typescript might not be compliant to the unicode-escape-based spec.

```js
/**
 * @typedef {object} EmployeeCsv
 * @property {string} Emp#
 * @property {string} "First Name"
 */

function demo(/** @type EmployeeCsv */ emp) {
  // fails
  emp["Emp#"] = "abc";
  emp["First Name"] = "def";
}
```

I was able to make it work with the "new `@typedef` syntax" described in the [Closure Compiler wiki](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Annotating-Types#typedef), omitted entirely from [the `@typedef` page on jsdoc.app](https://jsdoc.app/tags-typedef.html).

```js
/**
 * @typedef {{
 *   "Emp#": string,
 *   "First Name": string,
 * }}
 */
let EmployeeCsv2;

function demo2(/** @type EmployeeCsv2 */ emp) {
  emp["Emp#"] = "abc";
  emp["First Name"] = "def";
}
```

(Note that both of these examples had TSC working in "JS mode", equivalent to parsing a file with a `.js` extension. This is set in TS Playground in the Config setting, top left.)

[Playground Link (JS)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.5&filetype=js#code/PQKhCgAIUgBAXAngBwKYBNUDNIG8D2ARgFaoDG8AvpAKIC2yANvoqqgMIDOAblDLMgBO+NIKR5O8QQEsAdgHNq9ZAGI+cISNRjEEqXMWQARADFpgyZAByAQzqojfYOHBYArrIrT8syJjr4ABSg-EhotAzMrBw80MCQqAwAlHhQkMDxWDbSjJxpicgA2kbKKkYAupAAvMY2hGRGANz5DMVmFvDWdg6VNUaYWE3glC4h6ggoGNh4uOqQxqVGAFyQkjIKADRzxu2WtvbLq-qb6pQjceCMqJ3KUWxc3ABMza4eXj5+ifiPwWBwYagIkwWPceI84glkql5gVioterV6kMYa1TOY9t0KtVjAMhiMgA)

---

Of course, in Typescript files, you can convert the JSDoc format to a Typescript interface definition.

```
interface EmployeeCsv {
  "Emp#": string,
  "First Name": string,
}

function demo(emp: EmployeeCsv) {
  emp["Emp#"] = "abc";
  emp["First Name"] = "def";
}
```

[Playground Link (TS)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.5&filetype=ts#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKIFsAOAbA9gTwggGEBnAN2QG8AoZZAIg0wGIGAuZUsKUAcwA0dRgDFgUbsgBycdBA5ce-IQF8aNGAFcQCMMFwhkAEwjpcAClOZOzPIRIUAlNWFWA2kyxsAusgC8jHAARggMANyuWB5iEmDSsvK+AQwmMOE0akA)

Comment: Thanks! I'll get this updated in my JSDoc + TypeScript template project as well: https://github.com/BeyondCodeBootcamp/jsdoc-typescript-starter/issues/3